# Is it possible to use package semPlot with R 3.6.2?

Tags: r, graph, upgrade, semplot

I upgraded R to version 3.6.2 and have discovered that package semPlot will not work. It installs without any problems, but when I try to load it I get the message,

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘semPlot’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘ggm’

I then tried to install ggm but get the following warning and error:

> Warning in install.packages : dependency ‘graph’ is not available
>
> There is a binary version available but the source version is
>   later:
>       binary source needs_compilation ggm    2.3    2.5             FALSE installing the source package ‘ggm’ trying URL
>   'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggm_2.5.tar.gz' Content type
>   'application/x-gzip' length 109414 bytes (106 KB) downloaded 106 KB
>
> ERROR: dependency ‘graph’ is not available for package ‘ggm’  removing
>   ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/ggm’
>   Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘ggm’ had
>   non-zero exit status"

I then tried to install graph, but it says:

> package ‘graph’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2).

I wondered if anyone else had experienced this problem, and had any solutions so I can load semPlot with R 3.6.2?

Many thanks.

Comment: `graph` is available here https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/graph_1.64.0.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have `R 3.6.2` and get all errors you get. But when I try to install the `semPlot` package from GitHub, it works fine, as follows:

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)

install_github('SachaEpskamp/semPlot',  dependencies = T)
library(semPlot)
```

Please not that I tried the `cran/semPlot` repository but didn't work for me, whereas `SachaEpskamp/semPlot` does.

Hope you get it working.